# `loop` and `with-redefs` do not play well together

Tags: clojure

I have some code which I refactored only to find out something was broken with `loop`. After some debugging I found out `loop` and `with-redefs` do not play well together. I realize it may not make sense to use `with-redefs` inside a loop, but I didn't expect it to not work. I'm not sure if its intentional or not.

This is an MCVE I've created to demonstrate the "problem":

```
(loop [test 3]
  (with-redefs []
    (if (zero? test)
      "done"
      (recur (dec test)))))
```

This gives me:

> Mismatched argument count to recur, expected: 0 args, got: 1

Removing the `with-redefs` works as expected:

```
(loop [test 3]
  (if (zero? test)
    "done"
    (recur (dec test))))
```

and returns `"done"`.

What is the reason the first piece of code does not work? Is this intentional?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The explanation is in the macroexpansion of `with-redefs`:

```
(macroexpand-1
 '(with-redefs []
    (if (zero? test)
      "done"
      (recur (dec test)))))
```

returns:

```
(with-redefs-fn {}
  (fn []
    (if (zero? test)
      "done"
      (recur (dec test)))))
```

where you can see that because a new `fn` has been introduced, the `recur` is going to refer to that `fn` rather than the farther-away `loop` (which explains the arity exception).

There are a variety of other macros that are "incompatible" with `loop` in this way, because the `recur` needs to be in the tail position with respect to `loop`, and if the `recur` occurs inside a macro call, the macro may be manipulating the code such that the `recur` is no longer in tail position.

For `with-redefs` in particular (and a variety of other situations), a workaround could be:

```
(loop [test 3]
  (let [[recur? val]
        (with-redefs []
          (if (zero? test)
            [false "done"]
            [true (dec test)]))]
    (if recur?
      (recur val)
      val)))
```